# AngularJS - orderBy vote count

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-orderby, variable-length

```
<a ui-sref="detail({id: post._id})" ng-if="post" ng-repeat="post in posts |
 orderBy : post.votes.length | limitTo:10" class="list-group-item">
        <div class="row">
            {{post.votes.length}}
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <h5 class="no-margin-top"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-{{post.type}}-sign"></span> <strong>{{post.birdname}}</strong></h5>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div class="thumbnail no-border no-margin-bottom"> 
                    <img ng-src="{{post.picture}}" alt="bird"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <h5>&#160;<span class="fa fa-map-marker"></span> {{post.place}}</h5>
                <h5>&#160;<i class="fa fa-user"></i> {{post.author}}</h5>
                <h5>&#160;<i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> <span am-time-ago="post.created_at"></span></h5>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />
    </a>
```

When trying `post.votes.length` I get the number of votes (likes) done to that specific post and I'm trying to order them from most amount to least.

In my controller I am simply retrieving all the posts and returning them to the partial:

```
app.controller('dashboardCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', 'postApi', function($scope, $http, postApi){
    $scope.posts = [];
    $scope.pageSize = 4;
    $scope.currentPage = 1;

    postApi.getAllPosts()
        .then(function(res) {
            $scope.posts = res.data.filter(function(posts) {
                return posts;
        });
    });
}]);
```

But the ng-repeat doesnt sort by the highest value. Just to make sure that it is passing along the amount, I did a `{{post.votes.length}}` right underneath, which does count the amount correctly.

The votes are an array inside the post with an id of all the votes done (linked with a refrence) as shown below:

```
{
"_id": "574ddaab594d3e6514ddf6e7",
"created_at": "2016-05-31T18:40:43.727Z",
"author": "Author",
"userId": "154815165165",
"body": "body",
"type": "ok",
"__v": 32,
"votes": [
"574ede99277c97a810379328",
"574ee07b277c97a81037932a"
],
"comments": []
}
```

So as you can see above the post with id `574ddaab594d3e6514ddf6e7` has 2 'likes' aka votes.
*Lets take this as an example:* if all the other posts had 1 vote, but this one had 2, I would want to show this vote on top.

Comment: Try to quote post.votes.length: `ng-repeat="post in posts |
 orderBy : 'post.votes.length' | limitTo:10"`

Comment: @RomanKoliada I had already tried that, doesn't work either

Comment: `ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy : 'votes.length' | limitTo:10"` should work.

Comment: I'm not quite sure but sometimes a blank-space can cause errors. Have you tried writing it like `orderBy:'post.votes.length'`?

Comment: Just tried it, same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put below filter in your ng-repeat

```
ng-repeat="post in posts |  orderBy : 'votes.length' : true | limitTo:10"
```

Instead of

```
ng-repeat="post in posts | orderBy : post.votes.length | limitTo:10"
```

[Click here to show example in codepen](http://codepen.io/tuhincse24/pen/beNaVQ)

Answer (score -1):

```
<a ui-sref="detail({id: post._id})" ng-if="post" ng-repeat="post in posts |
  orderBy : -post.votes.length | limitTo:10" class="list-group-item">
```

if i understood correctly this might work